# Issues with forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

when I am submitting the form, I am getting `KeyError` at **password1 in forms.py line 25  password1=self.cleaned_data['password1']**. The code of files is given below:

The code of forms.py is:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from drinker.models import Drinker

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
       username   = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
       email      = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
       password   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
       password1   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

       class Meta:
              model=Drinker
              exclude=('user',)

       def clean_username(self):
                username=self.cleaned_data['username']
                try:
                      User.objects.get(username=username)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                      return username
                raise forms.ValidationError("The Username is already taken, please try another.")
       def clean_password(self):
                password=self.cleaned_data['password']
                password1=self.cleaned_data['password1']
                if password != password1:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("The Password did not match, please try again.")
                return password
```

The code of html file is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#id_birthday" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if form.errors %}<p>Please correct the following fields:</p>{% endif %}
<div class="register_div">
    {% if form.username.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.username.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="username"{% if form.username.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Username:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.username }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">
    {% if form.email.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.email.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="email"{% if form.email.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Email:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.email }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">
    {% if form.password.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.password.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="password"{% if form.password.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Password:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.password }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">
    {% if form.password1.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.password1.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="password1"{% if form.password1.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Password1:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.password1 }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">
    {% if form.birthday.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.birthday.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="birthday"{% if form.birthday.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Birthday:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.birthday }}</p>
</div>
<div class="register_div">
    {% if form.name.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.name.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="name"{% if form.name.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Name:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.username }}</p>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

the view file is

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from drinker.models import Drinker
from django.template import RequestContext
from drinker.forms import RegistrationForm

def DrinkerRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
         #return render_to_response('register')
         form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
                  user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])

                  user.save()
 #                 drinker=user.get_profile()
  #                drinker.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
   #               drinker.birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday']
    #              drinker.save()
                 drinker=Drinker(user=user,name=form.cleaned_data['name'],birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday'])  
                  drinker.save()    
                  return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
         else:
                  return render_to_response('register.html',{'form':form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))  
    else:
         ''' user is not submitting the form, show them a blank registration form '''

         form = RegistrationForm()
         context={'form':form}
         return render_to_response('register.html',context , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django calls `clean_xxx()` methods for each field in the form. When a field is valid, it will add the key/value to `cleaned_data`. When Django calls `clean_password` and it has not yet processed the field `password1` then `cleaned_data` won't contain a key/value pair for `password1`. That is the error you are currently getting.

To fix it, you need to move the validation of the passwords to `clean()` which is called after Django has checked each of the field individually. This method can be used to perform validation which concerns multiple fields of the form (i.e., the form as a whole).

This also makes sense because the error you want to raise is about the mismatch between `password` and `password1`, not just the field `password` (the field that you are currently cleaning).

Comment: **I got that!!**

But now I am submitting the form
_if user is authenticated then it goes to the_ **profile page**
but when I try to register the user it always redirect to the register.html
I have checked my code and I found that `if form.is_valid():
                  user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])

                  user.save()
`

**this part is not working**